# Unsure how to remove double quotes around a tagged object element retrieved from a backend database

Tags: javascript, string, material-ui, double-quotes

Given the following object which is being returned from a backend db table:

```
let a = {
  id: 1,
  menu_icon: "<AssessmentIcon />"
}
```

how can I remove the double quotes around `"<AssessmentIcon />"` which is a material-ui icon ?

I just need this to be `<AssessmentIcon />` - no double quotes.

I have tried `a.menu_icon.slice(1, -1)` but this removes the actual tags `<` and `>`

Comment: Unsure how this `Dynamic tag name in jsx and React` question is relevant to mine?

Comment: You can't achieve this by manipulating the string, at least not without using eval(). You'll need a lookup table { '<AssessmentIcon />': () => <AssessmentIcon /> }, for example.

Comment: The quotes are just there to define the object as a string. They will not be in the string result. Do you actually just not want it to be a string in the first place?

Comment: @AdamHarte - correct. if I can make it not be a string that is retrieved from the backend db, that should solve my problem.

Comment: Will this work? `const e = React.createElement(a.menu_icon.replace(/(\W)/g,''));`